# Oracle Databases with ldap, How we will provide Django connection DATABASE json in settings

Tags: python, django, database, oracle, ldap

I have a oracle database JDBC connection string `jdbc:oracle:thin:@ldap://<LDAP Server String>/<Database Service Name><LDAP Context>` is in format. How we will use these parameters in Django application as a database?

Answer (score 0):

Can you check out the [JDBC developer guide](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/jjdbc/data-sources-and-URLs.html#GUID-F1841136-BE7C-47D4-8AEE-E9E78CA1213D) for using LDAP ?